# What famous line does this Linux command line represent?

Tags: rebus, computer-puzzle

The following shows a Linux command line with a `#` prompt:

```
#




                            echo -e 'AAAAHHH!!!\a' > /dev/null




#
```

It represents a famous line from a work of fiction.  What line is that?

Comment: Clever variation on rebuses!

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The answer is

> "In space no one can hear you scream." The tagline for the Alien movie.

```
echo -e 'AAAAHHH!!!\a'
```

> This is a scream. (Added bonus of \a telling the system to beep.)

```
> /dev/null
```

> This redirects the output to the null device, effectively muting it.

```
#








#
```

> Space!

Comment: That's correct, good job!

Comment: [SPAAAAAAACE!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xeKMS62GrTI)

Answer (score 13):

> In space, no one can hear you scream

The scream gets written to /dev/null, which discards all data written to it. In other words no one receives the text, it gets lost 'in the void'.

Not sure what the beep represents though.

Comment: That's correct, although Ian beat you to it.  The beep is there to make sure the word "hear" is part of the answer.