# Another Linux movie command

Tags: knowledge, rebus, computer-puzzle

Inspired by [this question,](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/11025/14010) here's another Linux command representing a famous line:

```
cp -a ~she ~
```

Which line is it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My best guess would be

> "I'll have what she's having" from *When Harry met Sally, 1989* 
>  
>  You are copying (*cp*) everything from user *she* to the current user (*~*) while trying to keep everything as close as possible to the orginal (by using option *-a*). 
>  
> So, I (the current user) will have what the user (*she*) is having (by copying the data with the -a option)

Comment: And your best guess is correct. Well done!

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Please fill out your answer to explain your reasoning!

Comment: And your reasoning is correct, too.