# Yet another movie quote hidden in Linux

Tags: knowledge, rebus, computer-puzzle

Inspired by [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/73966/another-linux-movie-command) and [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11025/what-famous-line-does-this-linux-command-line-represent), can you guess the famous movie quote hidden in this Linux block?

```
infant:~$ ps a | grep 13179
13179 pts/20   R      0:18 /bin/bash ./Z
13181 pts/20   S+     0:00 grep --color=auto 13179
infant:~$ kill 13179
infant:~$ kill 13179
bash: kill: (13179) - No such process
[1]+  Terminated              ./Z
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> "Zed's dead, baby. Zed's dead." from Pulp Fiction. My guess is because you're attempting to kill a process that's been terminated already. The system replies with a message that Z's been terminated and process is not found on the second attempt to kill the process.

Comment: Can you explain why you think that?

Comment: That's right, but infant as the user contributes as well. Specifically, the message being read to that specific user.

Comment: @ChaseGilbert, I didn't want to overthink it, since it could also mean that Fabienne killed `./Z`. I assume it has something to do with the "baby" part, could you clarify?

Comment: @Maksim Vi Just think of the termination message being read to the user for the quote to work. I see how you were interpreting it, but that's not quite what I was going for haha.